# How do I retrieve email templates from a sandbox using sfdx

Tags: email-template, salesforcedx

Is it possible to retrieve email templates using sfdx?

I would assume that I could get them using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:Folder/TemplateName` but everything I try results in

```
=== Retrieved Source
No results found
```

EDIT: Solved with AngelSalazars answer.

In case anyone finds it useful, my solution to get all email templates from an org is

```
emails="`sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "select Id, Name, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix, Folder.DeveloperName, Folder.NamespacePrefix, FolderId from EmailTemplate" -r json | jq -r '.result.records[] | "EmailTemplate:" + if (.Folder) then if (.Folder.NamespacePrefix) then .Folder.NamespacePrefix + "__" else "" end + .Folder.DeveloperName else "unfiled$public" end + "/" + if (.NamespacePrefix) then .NamespacePrefix + "__" else "" end + .DeveloperName + ","' | tr -d '\n'`"
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "${emails%%,}"
```

Comment: are you trying to retrieve personal folder?

Comment: Did you try using the template unique name?

Comment: It should be like this - sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:YOUR_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_UNIQUE_NAME

Comment: I am trying to retrieve from a public folder. I dit try using only the template name but that doesn't work. I expected it should be Folder/DeveloperName because that is how you have to put them in a package.xml

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: If you are a windows user-try running the solution in bash command

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, you have to escape the `$` and `/` characters

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:unfiled\$public\/YOUR_TEMPLATE_API_NAME -u YOUR_ORG
```

Comment: Thanks. Another problem for me was that I had to add a namespace prefix to the folder.

Comment: To add more clarity - the 'unfiled\$public\' is the folder name with the $ escaped (as AngelSalazar mentioned). So if you have a folder with the name `foo` and an email template with the api name of 'foo_test' you would retrieve with:

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:foo\/foo_test -u YOUR_ORG_ALIAS`

Answer (score 6):

After trying just about every combination I can think of / find on the internet, this worked for me:

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:'unfiled$public'/EMAIL_TEMPLATE_API_NAME`

The kicker is the single quotes around `unfiled$public`. Hope this helps and please upvote me if this works for anyone!

Comment: As of 2023 the other answers did not work for me but this one did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I think there's an easier way to this if put the -m arguments in double-quotes you should have to use the escape character.

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "EmailTemplate:unfiled public/YOUR_TEMPLATE_API_NAME" -u YOUR_ORG`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder named : **My Folder** than it will be

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u userAlias -m "EmailTemplate:My_Folder\/Email_Template_Name"
```