# retrieve all email templates with sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, email-template

I am trying to generate a command or set of command that will retrieve all my email templates.

I am using sfdx and do not want to use ant or package.xml

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256962/how-do-i-retrieve-email-templates-from-a-sandbox-using-sfdx) post only talks about getting a specific email template, I want a method to get all of them.

Is that that possible?

If not - what is the preferred way on doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike other metadata types `EmailTemplate` metadata type does not support a wild character.

Also, it will need you to specify the folder name as well to retrieve the metadata.

It will be some manual work unless you script it using Bash or Node.js,

Here is how I would approach manually,

**Step 1**

Create a SOQL to get all the folder names of Type Email

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "Select Id, Name, DeveloperName, Type, NamespacePrefix from Folder where DeveloperName!=null and Type='Email'"
```

**Step 2**

For every folder in step1, note down the `developername` and use the below command.

```
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m EmailTemplate --folder=<developernameoffolder>
```

**Step 3**

From the output `JSON` look for the field `fullName` to construct a package.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
    <members>unfiled$public/MarketingProductInquiryResponse</members>
    <members>unfiled$public/SalesNewCustomerEmail</members>
    ....
    ....
    <name>EmailTemplate</name>
  </types>
 <version>53.0</version>
 </Package>
```

Retrieve using package.xml using the `mdapi`

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapipkg -u <username> -k ./package.xml
```

Alternatively `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "EmailTemplate:<folderdevelopername>:<templatedevelopername>"` for n times.

Comment: I've written a similar script; it's not too bad, but it is awfully obnoxious that there isn't a nice way to build this with a single command. Same for other types of folders that don't support wild cards, like Reports.

Comment: Ya! Mind opening a feature request on the official git repo and we can socialize a bit to get into developer tooling teams backlog.

Comment: Thank you Monith for the answer. @sfdcfox - can you please share this script?

Comment: @ItaiShmida I don't have that script, it was for a previous role, but I can write it again this weekend or so. It was just a simple node script that called sfdx to list the metadata, reads the resulting output, then builds the appropriate XML for a second pass. It's really not that bad, maybe like 25 lines of code or so.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above Mohit answer, below may can help, you just need to call this function from powershell and pass the username of the org

function retrieveEmail ([string] $u) {

```
$soql_query = "Select DeveloperName from Folder where DeveloperName!=null and (Type='Email' OR Type = 'EmailTemplate')"

$output = sf data query --query $soql_query -o $u --json | ConvertFrom-Json


$pxml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Package xmlns='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata'><types>"

foreach ($result in $output.result.records) {
    $value = $result.DeveloperName
    $metadata = sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m EmailTemplate --folder $value -u $u --json | ConvertFrom-Json

    foreach ($d in $metadata.result) {
        $metaValue = $d.fullName
        Write-Host($metaValue)

        $pxml += "<members>$metaValue</members>"
    }

}
$pxml += "<name>EmailTemplate</name></types><version>53.0</version></Package>"

Set-Content -Path "PATH To Copy The XML" -Value $pxml
```

}

Note: This script will respond slow based on number of Email Templates in the Org