# How could i retrieve all email templates to VSC using sfdx or manifest?

Tags: salesforcedx, email-template, visualstudiocode, manifest

I need to retrieve all email templates to my visual studio code to apply a general replacement on the text of those templates.
I give a try to the solutions provided at those links [retrieve all email templates with sfdx](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363127/retrieve-all-email-templates-with-sfdx)
and [How do I retrieve email templates from a sandbox using sfdx](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256962/how-do-i-retrieve-email-templates-from-a-sandbox-using-sfdx) (AngelSalazars answer)
but i was not able to make it work.

Please, any one have an idea for a eventual solution ?

Thank you,

Kindly

Comment: you want to retrieve from scratch or sandbox? if sandbox  then 1st make your sfdx project default org is your sandbox then retrieve(download)  emailtemplates from  org browser

Comment: Yes, it is from sandbox. How could i download/retrieve from org browser please ?

Comment: Probably you are missing something from the given solution. If you are unable to use sfdx approach, then you can download metadata using Salesforce inspector and access that folder in vs code. But, the sfdx approach will be better always as you can deploy your changes easily.

Comment: @Guarav Suthar, yes finally i went toward this approach: import email templates via Salesforce inspector/dataloader. Thank you for your response